# What is the significance of the sheriff's colored sunglasses in Kill Bill vol 1?

Tags: kill-bill

In Kill Bill vol 1 as the Sheriff is driving up to the murder scene at the church a view of the dashboard of his car reveals a collection of different colored sunglasses. Later inside the church he removes his sunglasses and it seems he is wearing green-tinted glasses.

[image]

So is this just an attempt at coolness or is there an actual significance to the colors and green in particular?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's a direct reference to a similar image in [***Gone In 60 Seconds***](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0071571/) (1974)

[image]

BTW: "Eleanor" is a customized 1971 Ford Mustang Sportsroof (redressed as 1973)

[image]
<sup>Source - Wikipedia</sup>

As for the "significance" of the sunglasses, they seem just to have been an affectation of the film's creator H. B. "Toby" Halicki.

> Toby's office was a gargantuan garage displaying toy cars, real cars and all sorts of antique bric-a-brac. If you saw "Gone in Sixty Seconds" you'll recall the many pairs of aviator-style sunglasses scattered about Eleanor's dashboard. In real life, it was his Rolls Royce which received the Toby treatment.
>
> <sup>[Source](http://tcotrel.tripod.com/gone/halicki.html)</sup>

Comment: Is there any significance to this display of sunglasses in the source film though?

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan Possibly a joke hinting at 'rose-tinted glasses', https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose-colored_glasses. But that's just a long shot guess.

Comment: @MauricioPasquierJuan - Kill Bill is basically a collection of references to other movies and genres.

Comment: ?Possibly from shooting sports?  The color of glass affects contrast and depth perception.  Magenta for overcast, yellow for sharpening contrast, brown for bright conditions, gray for very bright (snow) conditions...

Comment: @Blackbeagle that would seem relevant for law enforcement.